# failure to push to heroku on git deploying node server

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, push

Im using heroku for testing a server I have followed other examples about this but I keep getting the same error that I dont see anywhere. I have even tried deleting my repo and my heroku app and starting again but i get the same error when using
`git push heroku master`.
`$ git push heroku master
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/football-app-development.git/': Could not resolve host: git.heroku.com`

`

```
$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "heroku"]
        url = https://git.heroku.com/football-app-development.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

`

Any help would be great!

Comment: execute `cat .git/config` and paste result here please.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have also started a new app I read about someone saying to start a new app so I tried it just fyi.
Code appended to question

Comment: Looks like a DNS issue.  Can you ping git.heroku.com?

Comment: Tried there i got:
`$ ping git.heroku.com
Ping request could not find host git.heroku.com. Please check the name and try again.` @punund

Comment: This means something is very wrong with your internet or firewall setup, nothing to do with git or heroku or node.  Check your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Sorry now, but what am i looking for and how do I find the file? @punund

Comment: How do you find a file in your file system by known path, is that's what you are asking?  In any case, I don't think your question deserves any of its tags, and probably belongs to some other SO site.

Comment: oh really?? i never thought to check along the file path for a file that doesnt seem to be there. excuse my ignorance at not knowing why its not there and asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue I got it to work by uninstall got and the heroku tool belt and install both again.